# Rest Template exchange fails due to response content type being invalid

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, rest, spring-boot

I am having a problem retrieving the data from a AWS hosted API using springs restTemplate.

The following is my code

```
    public List<AccountLocation> getCircuitViewRooms(String clientApiKey) {
        String uri = circuitApiUrl + "school/rooms?api_key=" + clientApiKey;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().clear();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        List<AccountLocation> locations = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpEntity entity = getHeaders();
        ResponseEntity<?> resp = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        /*if(resp.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            CircuitViewRooms[] rooms = resp.getBody();
             for(CircuitViewRooms room : rooms) {
                AccountLocation loc = new AccountLocation();
                loc.setLocationName(room.getLaundryRooms().getLaundry_room_name());
                loc.setLocationId(room.getLocation());
                locations.add(loc);
            }
        }*/
        return locations;
    } 

    private HttpEntity<?> getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
        headers.add("x-api-key", xApiKey);
        return new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    }
```

I receive a 200 OK response but when it tries to use the httpMessageConverterExtractor it throws a org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "method.request.header.Content-Type": does not contain '/'

Stack Trace

```
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:534) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:924) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:133) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:90) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:994) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:977) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.upp.uppstudentapp.services.laundry.account_services.CircuitViewService.getCircuitViewRooms(CircuitViewService.java:38) ~[main/:na]
```

Postman returns but I also see that the content type in the response headers is "method.request.header.Content-Type"

I have also tried using object.class

Does anyone know of a way around this or a fix for this problem?

This is the documentation snippet for the api

> One notable difference is this implementation has the ability to produce output in either XML or JSON formats
>   whereas the previous API produced only XML. Additionally, method name parameters are not used in this
>   implementation - the full API path determines the applicable method.

edit 1: Added content-type attempts same exception

```
    private HttpEntity<?> getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("x-api-key", xApiKey);
        return new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    }
```

Also tried with the setContent.

Comment: Just put the right `Content-Type`.

Comment: You didn't defined content type

Comment: Tired that same response

Comment: what's the right content type and show/edit what you tried

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Hi @Dashwall, did you solve this?

Comment: Hi @zafirov. I did however I was lucky enough to get the content type changed by the company we were working with.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentType` expect `MediaType`, for JSON add:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: Same exception returned.